# Escaping a C++ string

Tags: c++, string, boost, escaping

What's the easiest way to convert a C++ std::string to another std::string, which has all the unprintable characters escaped?

For example, for the string of two characters [0x61,0x01], the result string might be "a\x01" or "a%01".

Comment: The easiest way to escape is through the emergency hatch right beside the `\0`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the Boost's [String Algorithm Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/string_algo.html).  You can use its [is_print](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/string_algo/quickref.html#id1721600) classifier (together with its operator! overload) to pick out nonprintable characters, and its [find_format()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id1718682) functions can replace those with whatever formatting you wish.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

struct character_escaper
{
    template<typename FindResultT>
    std::string operator()(const FindResultT& Match) const
    {
        std::string s;
        for (typename FindResultT::const_iterator i = Match.begin();
             i != Match.end();
             i++) {
            s += str(boost::format("\\x%02x") % static_cast<int>(*i));
        }
        return s;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string s("a\x01");
    boost::find_format_all(s, boost::token_finder(!boost::is_print()), character_escaper());
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Assumes the execution character set is a superset of ASCII and *CHAR_BIT* is 8.  For the *OutIter* pass a *back_inserter* (e.g. to a *vector<char>* or another string), *ostream_iterator*, or any other suitable output iterator.

```
template<class OutIter>
OutIter write_escaped(std::string const& s, OutIter out) {
  *out++ = '"';
  for (std::string::const_iterator i = s.begin(), end = s.end(); i != end; ++i) {
    unsigned char c = *i;
    if (' ' <= c and c <= '~' and c != '\\' and c != '"') {
      *out++ = c;
    }
    else {
      *out++ = '\\';
      switch(c) {
      case '"':  *out++ = '"';  break;
      case '\\': *out++ = '\\'; break;
      case '\t': *out++ = 't';  break;
      case '\r': *out++ = 'r';  break;
      case '\n': *out++ = 'n';  break;
      default:
        char const* const hexdig = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        *out++ = 'x';
        *out++ = hexdig[c >> 4];
        *out++ = hexdig[c & 0xF];
      }
    }
  }
  *out++ = '"';
  return out;
}
```

Comment: I thought && was a perfectly good operator.  You can even use it without needing an extra header file.

Comment: You can use *and* without a header in standard C++ too.  This was copied from another project and I forgot to change those to make up for MSVC's deficiencies.

Comment: Why did you write in such a way that it requires a `back_inserter` to be passed in? Isn't simply returning a string by value (which means moving it anyway) just fine?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that "easiest way" means short and yet easily understandable while not depending on any other resources (like libs) I would go this way:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

// s is our escaped output string
std::string s = "";
// loop through all characters
for(char c : your_string)
{
    // check if a given character is printable
    // the cast is necessary to avoid undefined behaviour
    if(isprint((unsigned char)c))
        s += c;
    else
    {
        std::stringstream stream;
        // if the character is not printable
        // we'll convert it to a hex string using a stringstream
        // note that since char is signed we have to cast it to unsigned first
        stream << std::hex << (unsigned int)(unsigned char)(c);
        std::string code = stream.str();
        s += std::string("\\x")+(code.size()<2?"0":"")+code;
        // alternatively for URL encodings:
        //s += std::string("%")+(code.size()<2?"0":"")+code;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot, despite the fiddling with stringstream, std::hex, and multiple casts. Would something like `char hex[5] = ""; ssize_t len = snprintf(hex, 5, "\\x%02x", c); s += std::string(hex, len);` in the `else` block work, too, or is there some gotcha I'm not seeing?

Comment: The OP didn't specifically ask for a pure C++ solution, but I thought it sounded like he preferred C++. And so I limited myself to that.
But yes, as far as I'm concerned your code would work just the same. (And would be a bit shorter.)

Comment: There is a bug in the solution. The isprint method expects an int >-1 and <= 255, you run into problems for characters with ASCII code >127, meaning a negative 
`char c`

Comment: Here is my version: https://gist.github.com/timmi-on-rails/173c496a9c5a33ad9df7c6428b9a077b

Comment: @Tom You are right. I correctly casted the character in the stringstream section, but not in inside `isprint`. I missed that despite testing higher ASCII codes due to the fact that gcc's implementation always seems to return false unless it's a printable character. Nevertheless undefined behavior is evil and so I corrected my original code.

Comment: @Scindix In windows with MSVC2017 an assertion window pops up.

Answer (score 4):

One person's unprintable character is another's multi-byte character. So you'll have to define the encoding before you can work out what bytes map to what characters, and which of those is unprintable.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the article about how to [Generate Escaped String Output Using Spirit.Karma](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/karma-examples/generate-escaped-string-output-using-spirit-karma/)?

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but since C++23 you can use debug format of strings by debug specifier `?`, e.g. `std::format("{:?}", "1\t\"\x2")` will get `"1\t\"\u{2}"`. The detail of escaping rule can be checked [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Formatting_escaped_characters_and_strings).

As of 11/2023, you may have a taste of it on Clang 16 with `-std=c++2b -fexperimental-library -stdlib=libc++` or msvc 19.37.