# Modify filepath to use in Printf

Tags: c++, c, windows, printf

I have a string which is something like `"c:\x\y\z"`

I want it in the form `"c://x//y//z"`

I tried using `stdString.replace("\","//");` but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can u try using stdString.replace("\\","//"); have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417588/escaping-a-c-string

Comment: Thanks.. a step ahead.. But this error comes up
error C2782: 'void std::replace(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &,const _Ty &)' : template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm(1317) : see declaration of 'std::replace'
1>          could be 'int'
1>          or       'char'

Comment: @RohitKabra my guess is you haven't read the answers. Have you checked out the link I posted? Have you read how `replace` works?

Comment: @RohitKabra: do you really want two slash characters (ie., two `'/'`) separating each path component?

Comment: Yeah. Want to use it for TempPath.. and In turn for CreateDirectory (TempPath.c_str(), NULL);

Comment: If you plan to use '/' as the separator you only need one, not two. `c:/temp/somefile.txt`

Answer (score 5):

If your string is `"c:\x\y\z"`, there are no `\` in your string. `\` denotes an escape character. Change your string to `"c:\\x\\y\\z"`.

Also, note how `replace` works - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

I don't think you can replace one character `'\\'` with two `"//"` directly. (I might be proven wrong).

Alternative:

```
std::stringstream ss;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < str.size() ; i++ )
{
    if ( str[i] == '\\' )
        ss << "//";
    else
        ss << str[i];
}
str = ss.str();
```

Comment: @Rohit Kabra, what he means is that using `\x` for example, makes that  `\` act as an escape character instead of the character `\`. So what u must do is use `\\x` instead. Unless if that string is being read in from an external source, in which case i believe this effect gets taken care of (it only affects hard-coded / constant values).

Comment: the string is being read from the external source and i need to convert is as i m appending it later on "//w".

Comment: @RohitKabra have you checked out the link I provided? I think you're misusing string.replace.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : I did. But then in stdString.replace("\\","//");   "//" has two characters.. so what do i do?

Comment: std::replace(stdString.begin(), stdString.end(), '\\', '//'); This is what i used..

Comment: @RohitKabra well, `std::replace` is hardly the same as `string::replace`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore  : It would be great if you could give me the statement.. i have tried since a long time and stuck here..

Comment: @RohitKabra I don't think you can directly replace one character with two characters in the string. You can use `std::replace(tdString.begin(), stdString.end(), '\\', '/');`.

Comment: Well what i notice is that "\\ is not read in the string itself.. I printed all the ascii characters of the string and "\\" doesnt get printed.. So all the conversion leads to nothng.!!

Comment: @RohitKabra `\\` will get printed as `\` because `\` marks an escape character.

Comment: @RohitKabra just like `'\n'` doesn't get printed as-is, but pastes a new line.

Comment: I converted it to ascii and then trying to print it. It should print the number 92. Wont it? Its as if the string doesnt contain "\"

Answer (score 0):

```
stdString.replace("\\","\/\/"); ?
```

Comment: `'/'` does not need to be escaped (though it will work on many compilers).  More importantly, `std::string::replace()` doesn't have a form that will match what you've posted (or do what it seems you expect it to do).

Answer (score 0):

if you hard coded the filepath in your source code then you may change value to `"c:\\x\\y\\z"`