# Escaped represention of std::string

Tags: c++

I'm executing the following code, have read this:

[Escaping a C++ string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417588/escaping-a-c-string)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

struct CharacterEscaper
{
    template<typename FindResultT>
    std::string operator()(const FindResultT& Match) const
    {
        std::string s;
        for (typename FindResultT::const_iterator i = Match.begin();i != Match.end();i++) 
        {
            s += str(boost::format("\\x%02x") % static_cast<int>(*i));
        }
        return s;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string s("start\x0aend");
    boost::find_format_all(s, boost::token_finder(!boost::is_print()), CharacterEscaper());
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
start\xffffffaend
```

I was expecting the following:

```
start\x0aend
```

having read this:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

What is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here:

- The escaper converts the character value to `int` before formatting it. This means that, if `char` is signed, values above `0x7f` will be sign-extended, giving the extra `f`s in the output. You can fix that by converting first to `unsigned char`, then perhaps to `unsigned` or `int`. (I don't know enough about the Boost formatter to know whether the second converion is necessary.)
- A hexadecimal escape sequence will include as many hexadecimal digits as it can find, so in this case it will be `\x0ae`. One way to fix that is by breaking the string literal into two, which will be recombined during compilation: `"start\x0a" "end"`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer. I should have written this: `"start\x0a" "end"`

Comment: Well, that's one solution. You do get similar problems with char values above `\x7F` though (because those are really values below 0). With what you have now, the most simple solution is to replace the `<int>` with `<unsigned>`.

Comment: @Mr Lister How might I fix this?

Comment: That is because it should be a `static_cast<unsigned char>`.

Comment: @Bart Right. I knew I was on the right track, but I wasn't thinking straight.