# string.find() returns true wrongfully

Tags: c++

Well the code explains what i am trying to do

```
auto haystack = wstring(L"\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Data\0\Path");
auto needle = wstring(L"\WOW6432Node\Data\0\Name");
auto found = haystack.find(needle) != haystack.npos;
cout << found << endl;
```

it returns true although `needle` is different than `haystack` notice the former ends with `\Path` while the latter ends with `\Name`... how could i exactly tell if certain string contains another ?

Comment: Instead of `\ `, try `\\ `. `\0` is terminating `0`.

Comment: Those \ in the strings, they have a special meaning in C and C++ string literals.

Comment: @AlexD this seems to be the answer, how could i ignore that and find a string in another normally like we can do in C# for instance with str.Contains(str2) ?

Comment: @AlexD stl strings can contain ` '\0'`s inside and they do not indicate end of string

Comment: IDK Why down voting what is wrong with the question ?

Comment: @mvidelgauz How does the constructor of `wstring` decide where the argument string ends?

Comment: @AhmedT.Yousef What do you mean "how could I ignore that?" You can't ignore that. `L"\a\b\c\d\n"` means "a wide string containing a bell character, a backspace, the letter c, the letter d, and a newline". If you want a wide string containing backslash a backslash b backslash c backslash d backslash n, you write it as `L"\\a\\b\\c\\d\\n"`.

Comment: @AlexD you are right! My bad...

Answer (score 2):

Due to the terminating '\0' the strings are shorter than you think:

```
auto haystack = std::wstring(L"\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Data");
auto needle = std::wstring(L"\WOW6432Node\Data");
```

The other unintended escape sequences should produce a compiler warning:

g++: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\R' (... and more)

You may look into: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Answer (score 0):

The `\` character is the escape character. To use the actual `\` character you need to escape it with `\\.` So your code needs to be changed like this:

```
auto haystack = wstring(L"\\REGISTRY\\MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Data\\0\\Path");
auto needle = wstring(L"\\WOW6432Node\\Data\\0\\Name");
auto found = haystack.find(needle) != haystack.npos;
cout << found << endl;
```

Comment: what if i am working with unknown strings and i wanna do a normal check for a constant ? like str.Contains(str2) in C# ?

Comment: @AhmedT.Yousef, then you need a general way to escape your string. For example, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417588/escaping-a-c-string

Comment: No need to do any special escaping if your string is read from a file, the Registry, the keyboard, etc. You only need to escape *literals*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
wstring haystack = wstring(LR"P(\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Data\0\Path)P");
wstring needle = wstring(LR"P(\WOW6432Node\Data\0\Name)P");
bool found = haystack.find(needle) != haystack.npos;
cout << (char*)(found?"True":"False") << endl;
```

\0 is a problem for you as it end constructor prematurely